# Check if string is reverse substring

Tags: c, string, c-strings, pointer-arithmetic

I need to write function which will check if string s2 is reverse substring of string s1, and return 1 if the condition is true. Function should be made using pointer arithmetic.

For example:

```
char s1[] = "abcdef";
char s2[] = "edc";
```

Function would return 1 because string s1 contains reverse string s2.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int reverseSubstring(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
  while (*s1 != '\0') {
    const char *p = s1;
    const char *q = s2;
    while (*p++ == *q++)
      if (*q == '\0')
        return 1;
    s1++;
  }
return 0;
}

int main() {
  char s1[] = "abcdef";
  char s2[] = "edc";
  printf("%d", reverseSubstring(s1, s2));
  return 0;
}
```

This function does the opposite. It checks if the string is substring and in my case it returns 0. It should return 1. How to modify this to work?

- Note: it is not allowed to use functions from the *string.h*, *stdlib.h* libraries, nor the *sprintf* and *sscanf* functions from the *stdio.h* library. It is not allowed to create auxiliary strings or strings in function or globally.

Comment: I don't see where you are reversing or searching backwards anywhere. You might want to write up the algorithm in pseudo-code first, make sure it makes sense, and then adjust your code accordingly.

Comment: @codproe Updated my answer a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slight modification to parts of your code:

```
const char *q = s2;

while(*q) q++; // Make q point to end of string

while (*p++ == *--q) // Decrement instead of incrementing
  if (q == s2) // If we have traversed complete substring
    return 1;
```

This is most likely good enough for a school task, which this most likely is. But it might be good to know that the operation `q--` will invoke undefined behavior for an empty string because it will make `q` point to the element before the string. That can be easily fixed. Just add `if(*s2 == '\0') return 1;` in the beginning of the function because an empty string is a substring of every string.

For completeness, here is a full version with some small fixes and optimizations. I also took the liberty of replacing a while loop with the library function `strlen` even if it was forbidden in the task. After all, the while loop is described above, and `strlen` is easy to implement on your own.

```
const char *
reverseSubstring(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    if(*s2 == '\0') return s1;

    const char *end = s2 + strlen(s2);

    while (*s1 != '\0') {
        const char *p = s1;
        const char *q = end;
         
        while (*p++ == *--q)) {
            if (q == s2) return s1;
        }
          
        s1++;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Note that I changed the return type. It returns `NULL` if no match is found, but if a match is found, it returns a pointer to the first match. That means it contains more information for free.